# Redirect in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, react-router

I am working on React with Typescript. "Redirect" doesn't seem to work for me.
I don't know what the problem is.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import store from "./ToDoStore"
import { Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
export class AddTodo extends React.Component {


refs: {
    name: (HTMLInputElement);
    description: (HTMLInputElement);
}

addTodo() {
    store.addTodo({ name: this.refs.name.value, description: this.refs.description.value })
    alert("Task added successfully");

 <Redirect to="/home" push/>
}

render() {

    return (
        <div id="addtodo">
            <TextField
                label='Add Todo' ref="name"
            />
            <br />
            <TextField
                label='Add Description' ref="description"
            />
            <br />
            <PrimaryButton text="Add" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

For `react-router-dom` v6 you will need to use `<Navigate />` instead of `<Redirect />`

ex.

```jsx
// use
<Navigate to="home" />

// not 
<Redirect to="home" />
```

See: [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63691192/4750488)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a typescript related issue. This is improper usage of `<Redirect/>`. You are trying to use a JSX component in a callback; this won't work. What you need to do is have some state change when a todo is added and conditionally render the `<Redirect/>` component when that state is true.

Try the below refactoring.

```
export class AddTodo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            shouldRedirect: false
        };

        this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
    }


    refs: {
        name: (HTMLInputElement);
        description: (HTMLInputElement);
    }

    addTodo() {
        store.addTodo({ name: this.refs.name.value, description: this.refs.description.value })
        alert("Task added successfully");

        this.setState({ shouldRedirect: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="addtodo">
                {
                    this.state.shouldRedirect ?
                        <Redirect to="/home" push/> :
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                                label='Add Todo' ref="name"
                            />
                            <br />
                            <TextField
                                label='Add Description' ref="description"
                            />
                            <br />
                            <PrimaryButton text="Add" onClick={this.addTodo} />
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!!!. It worked. But not on button click. Works directly on component render

Comment: If your beginning state is `shouldRedirect: false` and you used the ternary operator in the render method, it should not be redirecting on component load. I have to step out, I'll be back in a few hours. If you can't get it to work, post again here and I will make you a code sandbox example.

Comment: I was just practicing before my actual work started.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically navigate to another page using `this.props.history.push`.
    export your class with react-router-dom `withRouter(AddTodo)` for history to work like

```
//Import
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Your component will be

```
/*Your component*/
class AddTodo extends React.Component {
    ..your code goes here
}

export default withRouter(AddTodo);
```

And in your `addTodo` method

```
addTodo() {
     // Task added successfully
    if(success) { // Go to home page if success
        this.props.history.push('/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: They would first need to wrap their component with the `withRouter` HoC to have access to history.

Comment: @KyleRichardson - Yes that is correct. I have missed something and updated answer.  Thanks for hint!

Comment: @ElumalaiKaliyaperumal The only way this works is if I do export default withRouter(AddTodo as any); What is the correct type to cast as? Or should I make AddTodo's props extend some other interface?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface RouterProps {
  navigate: NavigateFunction;
  readonly params: Params<string>;
  location: Location;
}

export type WithRouterProps<T> = T & RouterProps;
type OmitRouter<T> = Omit<T, keyof RouterProps>;

export function withRouter<T>(
  Component: ComponentType<OmitRouter<T> & RouterProps>
) {
  return (props: OmitRouter<T>) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        location={location}
        navigate={navigate}
        params={params}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
}

class AddTodo extends React.Component {


refs: {
    name: (HTMLInputElement);
    description: (HTMLInputElement);
}

addTodo() {
    store.addTodo({ name: this.refs.name.value, description: this.refs.description.value })
    alert("Task added successfully");
    this.props.navigate("/home");
 }

render() {

    return (
        <div id="addtodo">
            <TextField
                label='Add Todo' ref="name"
            />
            <br />
            <TextField
                label='Add Description' ref="description"
            />
            <br />
            <PrimaryButton text="Add" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    )
}


export default withRouter(AddTodo);
```