# React: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting the following error when running `npm run start` in the terminal.

> Attempted import error: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

I have reinstalled `node_modules`, `react-router-dom`, `react-router`. Also restarted the terminal and my computer, but the issue persists.

**My code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { RouteWithLayout } from './components';
import { Minimal as MinimalLayout } from './layouts';

import {
  Login as LoginView,
  Dashboard as DashboardView,
  NotFound as NotFoundView
} from './views';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect
        exact
        from="/"
        to="/dashboard"
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={routeProps => <LoginView {...routeProps} data={data} />}
        exact
        layout={MinimalLayout}
        path="/login"
      />
      <Redirect to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Here is my `package.json` imports:

```
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
```

Comment: To keep everyone on their toes, react-router breaks compatibility with everything every now and then ;)

Answer (score 398, accepted):

For `react-router-dom` v6, simply replace `Redirect` with `Navigate`

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
.
{ component: () => <Navigate to="/404" /> }
```

Comment: The [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) documentation says it's a wrapper around [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate), whose doc page says "Important: It's usually better to use [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) in loaders and actions than this hook". That's all for main(6.4.3). So are those doc bugs?

Comment: @Sigfried `redirect` documentation says that it is equivalent to changing the route with 302 status. So it can't be used for navigating the application.

Comment: Thanks. Using <Navigate /> was bothering me while trying to debug some other problem and the component that (sometimes) returned <Navigate... /> was re-rendering once or twice before the url changed. Anyway, I fixed the bug, sweeping the annoyance under the rug.

Answer (score 106):

Redirect has been removed from **v6**.
You can replace **Redirect** with **Navigate**.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../home/Home';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 41):

`Redirect` component has been removed from the `react-router` version 6.

From [react router docs:](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20The%20%3CRedirect,in%20a%20useEffect.)

> The `<Redirect>` element from v5 is no longer supported as part of your
> route config (inside a ). This is due to upcoming changes in
> React that make it unsafe to alter the state of the router during the
> initial render. If you need to redirect immediately, you can either a)
> do it on your server (probably the best solution) or b) render a
> `<Navigate>` element in your route component. However, recognize that
> the navigation will happen in a `useEffect`.

---

If you want to use `Redirect` component, you will have to use react router version 5.

Alternatively, you can use [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate) component from react router v6. A `<Navigate>` element changes the current location when it is rendered

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

return (
  <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />
)
```

Note: `Navigate` is a component wrapper around [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) hook. You can use this hook to change routes programmatically.

Comment: Alternative to `Redirect` in react-router-dom v 6 is `Navigate`.

Example:
--

`<Redirect to='/' />` to `<Navigate replace to="/" />`


Reference Link: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate

Answer (score 17):

Redirect have been removed from **v6** but you **can** do it like that right now :

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to ="/" />}/>
```

Answer (score 13):

In react-router-dom version  **5.x.x > 6** we can use `<Redirect />`

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

{ component: () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> }
```

In react-router-dom version  **5.x.x < 6** we can use `<Navigate />`

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

{ component: () => <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> }
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't use the `Redirect` component because it has been removed from `react-router-dom` version 6.

You can use `react-router-dom` version 4.2.2. Just use the code below to install it.

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@4.2.2
```

or

```
yarn add react-router-dom@4.2.2
```

Answer (score 12):

switch `Redirect` into `Navigate`, it will work.

```
<Route path='/' exact>
   <Navigate to={`/documents/${uuidV4()}`} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Can NOT be used when you have multiple `Route`s wrapped in a `Routes`

Answer (score 10):

Redirect component has been removed from the react-router version 6, For react-router-dom v6, simply replace Redirect with Navigate

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

<Routes>
<Route path="/login" element={isLogin ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />}/>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 8):

For versions 6.X you must use the hook `useNavigate`.

Comment: I believe this only applies to functional components, no?

Answer (score 5):

```
import {
    Routes,
    Route ,
    Navigate
  } from "react-router-dom";

return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/products/:id' element={<Store/>} />

                 //replace Redirect with Navigate
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to ="/products" />}/>
            </Routes>

    );
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi I remembered there was a hook called useHistory, this hook still exist, this only have a few changes and was renamed to useNavigate. Using this and following one of the examples from the documentation, I did this rework for my protected routes:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

function ProtectedRoutes({ component: Component }, props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
    navigate("/");
  }, []);

  return <>{loading ? "Loading..." : <Component {...props} />} </>;
}

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

And in my Routes this is used like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthFirebaseHelper from "./helpers/AuthFirebaseHelper/AuthFirebaseHelper";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./helpers/ProtectedRoutes/ProtectedRoutes";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Home from "./components/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/authentication" element={<AuthFirebaseHelper />}></Route>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="/restricted"
          element={<ProtectedRoutes component={Dashboard} />}
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

export default App;

The documentation for [useNavigation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Answer (score 4):

As it is removed in `v6`, you can use this as an alternative.

```
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to call it from a function, and useNavigate was giving me problems for not being called from a component.

My site uses a context to hold drawers, so that drawers are always written to the same point and can stack if I want them to.

I added another property, commands

```
if (responseData.page?.url) {
  MyContext.command.make(<Navigate to={responseData.page.url />);
      setTimeout(()=>MyContext.command.clear(), 1500)
}
```

`command.clear()` just calls `setCommand(null)`, so I'm able to call this from components and functions alike, without React complaining about it like it does with useNavigate.

Answer (score -2):

Actually switch and redirect is the routers defined jn react-router version 5 and currently react-router version 6 so this will not word either
You used version 5 with switch and redirect or routers and to with version 6