# PublicRoute is not a Route component. All component children of Routes must be a Route or React.Fragment

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i am getting below error
[PublicRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>
my code is like this
PublicRoute.js is

> ```
>     import React from "react";
> import { Route } from "react-router";
>
> export default function PublicRoute(props) {
>   return <Route {...props} />;
> ```

```
}
```

App.js is

```
>  import "./App.css"; import Navbar from "./components/common/Navbar";
> import { Routes } from "react-router"; import PublicRoute from
> "./components/common/PublicRoute"; import Home from
> "./components/Home";
> 
> function App() {   return (
>     <div>
>       <Navbar />
>       <Routes>
>         <PublicRoute path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
>       </Routes>
>     </div>   ); }
> 
> export default App;
```

How can i solve above issue ?
For ref please find the attached image
[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171991/navigate-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-routes-must-be/70172518

Comment: Under <Routes>, you have provided <PublicRoute> and in that rendering Home as an element. So that's wrong. The correct way to do define your route is: `<Route path="/" element={<ComponentName />} />`