# Why does <Navigate /> in react-router v6 not work in <Routes /> like it does in the beta version?

Tags: reactjs

This is how I use it, and I don't think there should be much of a problem:

```js
export const ListScreen = ()=>{
    return (
        <>
            <h1>ListScreen</h1>
            <Link to={"/kanban"}>kanban</Link>
            <Link to={"/epic"} >epic</Link>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={"kanban"} element={<KanbanScreen/>}/>
                <Route path={"epic"} element={<EpicScreen/>}/>
                <Navigate to={window.location.pathname + "/kanban"}/>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

[image]

I am using react-router version 6.2.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigate is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171991/navigate-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-routes-must-be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171991/navigate-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-routes-must-be/70172518): `Routes` component only accept `Route` component as child

So in your case, instead of using directly `<Navigate />`  in the `Routes` component, I'd rather do like this:

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={window.location.pathname + "/kanban"}/>}
```

But instead of redirecting, it would make more sense (to me) to have a default `Route` instead, that points directly to the default component to display, like this:

```
<Route path="*" element={<KanbanScreen/>}
```