# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. i have tried to use chatGPT but not getting anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

when user is false i want to use useNavigate to direct user to /register page instead of going to home page but it keeps giving me an error: (useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.) Keep in mind I do not want to use redirect because my current version of react-router-dom does not support it.
here is my code:

```
const App = () => {
  const user = false;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#0b0b0b]">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          {user ? (<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />) : (navigate("/register"))}
          <Route path="/movies" element={<Home type="movie" />} />
          <Route path="/series" element={<Home type="series" />} />
          <Route path="/watch" element={<Watch />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `useNavigate` can only be used in a child of `<Router>`. `App` is not a child of `Router`. Use [`<Navigate>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) instead

Comment: i have tried <Navigate> as well and that does not work

Comment: It should work, can you show what you have tried?

Comment: i used 
{user ? (<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />) : (<Navigate to="/register" />)}

Comment: still getting the error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171991/navigate-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-routes-must-be

Comment: `<Route path="/" element={user  ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/register" />} />`

Comment: A simple solution would be to put the Router component around the App component itself, which is probably called in your `index.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

The `useNavigate` hook can't be used outside any router that provides the routing context for it. To resolve the error you should promote the `Router` component that provides the routing context higher in the ReactTree than the `App` component so it can be used there.

You don't need to use the `useNavigate` hook in the `App` component though. Simply render a `Navigate` component in its place to issue a declarative navigation action.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const user = false;
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#0b0b0b]">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          {user
            ? <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            : <Navigate to="/register" replace />
          }
          <Route path="/movies" element={<Home type="movie" />} />
          <Route path="/series" element={<Home type="series" />} />
          <Route path="/watch" element={<Watch />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It seems the code is heading in the direction of a route protection implementation. See my answer [here](/a/66289280/8690857) for a complete example.