# how to redirect to homepage after login in reactjs using SPA

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mern

my problem: after clicking login, my page doesn't redirect to home page but still stays on login page, even though check in Application I have successfully logged in, I have to F5 to get everything back to normal after login. how to click login can redirect to home page when using **SPA** in **reactjs**

Thank you

func submit

```js
onSubmit: async () => {
      const loginData = await loginUser(values);
      console.log(loginData);
      if (loginData.success) {
        navigate('/dashboard/app', { replace: true });
      } else console.log(values);
    }
```

Router:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
// layouts
import DashboardLayout from './layouts/dashboard';
import LogoOnlyLayout from './layouts/LogoOnlyLayout';
//
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import DashboardApp from './pages/DashboardApp';
import Products from './pages/Products';
import Blog from './pages/Blog';
import User from './pages/User';
import NotFound from './pages/Page404';
//
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/AuthContext';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function Router() {
  const {
    authState: { authLoading, isAuthenticated }
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let body;
  if (authLoading) {
    body = 0;
  } else if (isAuthenticated) {
    body = 1;
  } else {
    body = 2;
  }
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        {
          element: body === 1 ? <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" replace /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
        },
        { path: 'app', element: body === 1 ? <DashboardApp /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> },
        { path: 'user', element: body === 1 ? <User /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> },
        { path: 'products', element: body === 1 ? <Products /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> },
        { path: 'blog', element: body === 1 ? <Blog /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <LogoOnlyLayout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'login',
          element: body === 1 ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <Login />
        },
        { path: 'register', element: body === 1 ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <Register /> },
        { path: '404', element: <NotFound /> },
        {
          path: '/',
          element: body === 1 ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
        },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
      ]
    },
    { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Basic debugging: what's the output of `console.log(loginData);`? is `loginData.success` truthy? Does the navigate() line get called? Also, if this is a form you're submitting, are you calling .preventDefault(); on the submission event?

Comment: I don't call preventDefault();  because I use Formik. After I click login, isAuthenticated doesn't change to true right away, I need to press F5

Answer (score 1):

*I don't think Navigate exists within react-router-dom. Are you thinking of Redirect?*

*https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect*

EDIT: Wait my bad, it is in V6 -> https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690695/react-redirect-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom

Comment: Redirect component has been removed from the react-router V6.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to redirect to another Route:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {

let history = useHistory(); //add this line

   onSubmit: async () => {
     const loginData = await loginUser(values);
       console.log(loginData);
       if (loginData.success) {
         history.push('/dashboard/app'); //add this instead
       } else console.log(values);
     }
   }
```